# mysql join two tables with registry table using join query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i want to join 2 mysql tables .but join information is in a separate table .let's say i have 3 table named student ,course and reg contain id of student and course he does.

```
student table

    s_id | name
    1    | miki    
    2    | foly    
    3    | oski  



course table    
        c_id | name
        101  | c++    
        102  | java    
        103  | ruby 


reg  table

    s_id | c_id
    1    | 101    
    1    | 102    
    2    | 101
```

now i want to get all the course  someone do.i wrote sql query for that without using join query .but i want to do same thing using join query .this is my query

```
SELECT c.name FROM student as s,course as c,reg as r where r.s_id=s.s_id and r.c_id=c.c_id and s.name='miki';
```

Comment: show us your query and expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statement

```
SELECT c.name
FROM student as s,couse as c,reg as r 
where r.s_id=s.s_id and r.c_id=c.c_id and s.name='miki'
```

is join too, `,` between table names is short cut for `cross join`, so you already using joins (actually you have some conditions in `where`, so RDBMS will optimize it to `inner join`)

but, of course you can rewrite it to different syntax:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM couse as c
inner join
reg as r 
on (c.c_id = r.c_id and r.s_id=(select s_id from student where name='miki'));
```

another syntax:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM couse as c
inner join
reg as r 
on (c.c_id = r.c_id)
inner join
student as s
on (r.s_id=s.s_id and s.name='miki');
```

and another one:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM couse as c
inner join
reg as r 
on (c.c_id = r.c_id)
inner join
student as s
on (r.s_id=s.s_id)
where s.name='miki';
```

depending on bunch of conditions performance of these 4 queries can be different, but results will be the same

Answer (score 2):

Just join all 3 tables to get the result

```
select c.name
from course c
join reg r on r.c_id = c.c_id
join student s on s.s_id = r.s_id
where s.name = 'miki'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT s.name,
  c.name
FROM student s
JOIN reg r
ON r.s_id = s.s_id
JOIN course c
ON c.c_id = r.c_id
WHERE s.name = "miki"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name, s.name as stud FROM course c
JOIN reg r on c.c_id = r.c_id 
JOIN student s on r.s_id = s.s_id 
WHERE s.name = 'miki'
```